# Why couldn't able to get response from a webpage? Android

Tags: android

I'm very new to Java/Android and I have a code to get the response of a webpage. I have a code like this, but for some reason the `BufferedReader`'s `in.readLine()` is always returning null.

```
URL url = new URL(endPoint);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

connection.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeout);
connection.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(encodedParams.getBytes().length));
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);

// Setup the POST payload
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(encodedParams);
wr.flush();
wr.close();

// Read the response
InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
```

Not sure where I'm making the mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the connection being set up in your code but I don't see it being connected. Try adding

connection.connect();

before you try to get the streams.

Answer (score 0):

Does the server return the repose.
I think you can simulate the request in browser and see what return.